# Crontab запуск с разными промежутками в разное время

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

Мне нужно запускать команду каждую минуту, если время между 15:00 и 23:00 и каждый час во все остальное время. Как это сделать

```
*/1    15-23        *     * *     /path/script
```

Это будет запускать только между 15 и 23 часами, но мне надо, чтобы и в остальное время работало. Или проще сделать новый таск?

Comment: Две разные задачи - два задания. А что скрипт один и тот же - это случайность.

Comment: ok, тогда так и сделаю